# Getting an error when assigning in built approval workflow sp2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am getting the following error when I am trying to implement aproval workflow for a document library settings.

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>   Correlation ID: a50396ce-ab64-4148-91a1-8fdebba1ed95
>
> Date and Time: 1/5/2012 5:40:02 PM

what has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

To get more details about the error download [ULSViewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer), attempt to approve the workflow again, write down the new Correlation ID and use ULSViewer to find out what the actual error is.